# Performance issues while splitting CLOB data

Tags: oracle, clob

In our project we have a table table1 which consists of Column Col6 of datatype CLOB.

Col6 column is having values separated by semicolon (for example: A; B; C; D)

We need to split values of this column based on semicolon as a separator. Our table is having huge amount of data and after splitting values we are expecting around 100 000 rows. We tried below queries but its taking more than an hour for execution.

How to resolve the performance issue?

We tried below two queries.

```
select
col1, col2, col3, col4,col5,
trim(regexp_substr(col6, '[^;]+', 1, level)) as dummy_col
from table1
CONNECT BY instr(col6, ',', 1, LEVEL - 1) > 0
and col6 is not null;


select
col1, col2, col3, col4,col5,,cast(trim(
  regexp_substr(col6, '[^;]+', 1, levels.column_value)
) as varchar2(1000)) as dummy_col
from table1,
    table(cast(multiset(
      select level from dual
      connect by level <= length (regexp_replace(col6, '[^;]+')) + 1
    ) as sys.OdciNumberList)) levels
    where col6 is not null;
```

Comment: If this is a system you control you should immediately change the data model and implement first normal form.

Comment: Actually its not possible. Because we create tables using excel sheets. We dynamically create table and that table have columns exactly similar to header columns of Excel sheet.

Comment: So, in excels sheet we have one column having values separated by semicolon and its character length is more that 4000 so when we are creating table dynamically this column is getting created with CLOB datatype.